# I want to get the values from slider in mxml and use it in as,thereby changing the layout

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, slider, mxml

(I am using flex builder)
    I have main mxml,this calls an AS file, layout is shown.That is working good.But I cant get the values from the slider dynamically into actionscript i.e, if the slide the slider the need to get these values in actionscript so that I can change the layout based on the values. I am using flexlib so that i can use lock region while dragging.

How do I get that.
mxml file is devud.mxml and As file is Devud.as

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[

import Devud;
private var my:Devud;

private function init():void{
 my = new Devud();
 Canvas.addChild(my.getUIComponent());}
</fx:Script>

<flexlib:HSlider id="slider" width="100%" height="50" 
                     thumbCount="2" tickColor="0X000000"
                     lockRegionsWhileDragging="true" allowTrackClick="true" maintainProjectionCenter="true"
                     change="dateChange();"
                     thumbSkin="mx.skins.spark.SliderThumbSkin"
                     trackSkin="mx.skins.spark.SliderTrackSkin"
                     trackHighlightSkin="mx.skins.spark.SliderTrackHighlightSkin" />
```

Thankyou,

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the value of the slider in ActionScript using [slider.value](http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/flexlib/baseClasses/SliderBase.html#value) .

If you want to execute code every time the value changes, you can listen to the [change](http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/flexlib/baseClasses/SliderBase.html#event%3achange) event.

If that doesn't answer your question, you're going to have to elaborate a bit more.

Comment: I tried using slider.value , I get this error

Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Whenn I use mx.core.Application.application.slider.value
I can get the value,but only once.

Comment: @user726629 Show us how / when you access the slider value.  You're probably trying to access it before the component is defined; and as such the slider will have no value.  You can read up on the Flex Component LifeCycle for more information: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html .

Comment: @user726629 IF it successfully answers your question, be sure to select it as such.  You'll get some "karma' points on the site and the answer will be clear to future people who come across the question.

Answer (score 0):

`I added startDate and endDate.Then I used these in my .AS

> `<fx:Script>`
>
> `<![CDATA[`
>
> `import Devud;`
>
> `private var my:Devud;`
>
> `private function init():void{`
>
> `my = new Devud();` 
>   `Canvas.addChild(my.getUIComponent());}`
>
> `public function dateChange():void{`
>
> `startDate.selectedDate = new
>   Date(slider.values[0]);`
>
> `endDate.selectedDate = new
>   Date(slider.values[1]);}`
>
> `</fx:Script>`
>
> `<flexlib:HSlider id="slider"
>   width="100%" height="50" 
>   thumbCount="2" borderColor="0Xff00cc"
>   lockRegionsWhileDragging="true"
>   allowTrackClick="true"
>   maintainProjectionCenter="true"
>
>   change="dateChange();"
>   liveDragging="true"
>
>   thumbSkin="mx.skins.spark.SliderThumbSkin"                     trackSkin="mx.skins.spark.SliderTrackSkin"
>
>   trackHighlightSkin="mx.skins.spark.SliderTrackHighlightSkin"
>   />`
>
> `<mx:HBox x="300" y="300"
>   height="50">`
>
> `<mx:Label text="Start Date :"/>`
>   `<mx:DateField id="startDate"/>`
>
> `<mx:Label text="End Date"/>`
>   `<mx:DateField id="endDate"/>`

in my .AS,mxml is devud.mxml.

> `var mn:devud =  new devud();`
>
> `trace(mn.startDate);`
>
> `trace(mn.endDate);`

I can get the values of the startDate every time I change the slider value